# How do I change tabs using JavaScript or jQuery without clicking on a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I need to change active tab when user clicks on certain element inside first tab. I am calling javascript function on click of that element. I am trying to set current tab inactive and make other tab active.

This is my HTML:

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Trial Balance</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Ledgers</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
     <span onclick="ShowNodeDetails(2,19,this);"> Loans (Liabillity)</span>         
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    //tab 2 content
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript code as well?

Comment: What do you mean by `when user clicks on certain element inside first tab`?

Comment: @ubaid ashraf masoody are you using any plugins ?

Comment: yeah, I did it. It was bootstrap plugin

Comment: Sory for late delay, but my internet went down the moment I posted this question and couldn't update this question. Then I got solution of it.